# write query to get expected output using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregation, group-concat

table name: transactions

| customer | debit | credit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 70 | 50 |
| a | 100 | 20 |
| a | 20 | 60 |
| b | 100 | 20 |
| b | 40 | 80 |
| b | 10 | 30 |
| c | 100 | 200 |
| c | 100 | 30 |
| c | 80 | 90 |
| d | 100 | 200 |
| d | 90 | 30 |
| d | 80 | 90 |
| e | 100 | 100 |
| e | 100 | 30 |
| e | 80 | 90 |

check who have positive or negative bal_type;
if(total of debit-total of credit>0 )
positive
else
negative

I try below:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN (SUM(debit)-SUM(credit))<0 THEN "negative" 
 ELSE "positive"
 END AS bal_type,
 customer
FROM 
    transactions
GROUP BY customer
```

MY OUTPUT:

| bal_type | customer |
| --- | --- |
| positive | a |
| positive | b |
| negative | c |
| negative | d |
| positive | e |

expecting:

| bal_type | customer |
| --- | --- |
| positive | e,a,b |
| negative | c,d |

NOTE: bal_type is derived type column. positive customer name should be order by DESC using there SUM(debit)-SUM(credit).
and negative customer name should be order by ASC using there SUM(debit)-SUM(credit).

Comment: Is it really intended to select "negative" for zero or is your logic incomplete?

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I got your point I update it.

Answer (score 3):

You need 2 levels of aggregation and `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function to concatenate the customers:

```
SELECT bal_type,
       GROUP_CONCAT(customer ORDER BY customer) AS customer
FROM (
  SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(debit)- SUM(credit) > 0 THEN 'positive' ELSE 'negative' END AS bal_type,
         customer
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY customer
) AS t
GROUP BY bal_type;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2Ri1JSXa).

Comment: Please check updates into question. I need query according to these changes.